# NDB, self and IntegerProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This is ridicolously trivial but i've spent half an hour trying to solve it.

```
class SocialPost(model.Model):
  total_comments=model.IntegerProperty(default=0)

def create_reply_comment(self,content,author):
    ...
    logging.info(self)
    self.total_comments=self.total_comments+1
    self.put()
```

In the logfile, i can see how total_comments is 0 but in the admin console, it is 1. The other fields are correct, except for this one.

Probably there's something wrong in that "default=0" but i can't find what is wrong.

Edit: full code of my function

def create_reply_comment(self,content,author):
        floodControl=memcache.get("FloodControl-"+str(author.key))
        if floodControl:
            raise base.FloodControlException

```
    new_comment= SocialComment(parent=self.key)
    new_comment.author=author.key
    new_comment.content=content
    new_comment.put()

    logging.info(self)
    self.latest_comment_date=new_comment.creation_date
    self.latest_comment=new_comment.key
    self.total_comments=self.total_comments+1
    self.put()
    memcache.add("FloodControl-"+str(author.key), datetime.now(),time=SOCIAL_FLOOD_TIME)
```

Where i call the function:

```
if cmd == "create_reply_post":
           post=memcache.get("SocialPost-"+str(self.request.get('post')))
           if post is None:
              post=model.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('post')).get()
              memcache.add("SocialPost-"+str(self.request.get('post')),post)
           node=node.get()
           if not node.get_subscription(user).can_reply:
               self.success()
               return


           post.create_reply_comment(feedparser._sanitizeHTML(self.request.get("content"),"UTF-8"),user)
```

Comment: but when you crate the log it's still 0 as you've not yet updated it? So when you check in the admin console (presumably the datastore) it will be 1 as you've incremented it.

Comment: It's fine the first time i do this but if i create another reply, self.total_comments is always 0 when i access it so it puts 0+1 in the datastore and it's obviously wrong because i want to track the total number of comments.

Comment: well, you'll need to store the total number of comments outside of the individual comments as every time you create a new comment it'll start at 0 again. So create a separate model to track total comments, and load and increment that when a new comment is made. Sharded counters are a good way to do that. https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters

Comment: This is a post, that contains many comments. The number of total_comments is stored in SocialPost, while here i'm creating a new SocialComment. This function is called over an existing (and supposedly the same) SocialPost everytime i create a new comment and not in SocialComment, as you assumed.

Comment: What happens at the beginning of create_reply_comment, and what is the code calling that function? Are you actually 'get'ting the SocialPost first, or just writing over the same key?

Comment: I'm gonna edit the first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling memcache.add before you make your change to total_comments, so when you read it back from memcache on subsequent calls, you're getting an out-of-date value from the cache. Your create_reply_comment needs to either delete or overwrite the `"SocialPost-"+str(self.request.get('post')` cache key.

[edit] Though your post title says you're using NDB (model.Model though? Hmm.), so you could just skip the memcache bits entirely, and let NDB do it's thing?

Comment: It's NDB. model.Model is due to a trick to implement it before it was actually included in official release or something like that. Anyway thanks, i'm gonna try this. Anyway what do you mean by "its thing"?

Comment: when you do Entity.get_by_id() or Key().get() then NDB will use memcache automatically, and when you put or delete it will clear out the appropriate cache entries.